# The summation of independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The random variables $N, X_1, X_2,...$ are independent, $N \in Po(\lambda) $, and $X_k \in Be(\frac{1}{2}),\ k \geq1$

$Y_1=\sum_{k=1}^{N}X_k \ and \ Y_2=N-Y_1$

I need to show that $Y_1 \ and \ Y_2$ are independent and find their distributions. This is from the conditional distributions chapter, so the solution can't really use the advanced tricks.

I am not sure where to begin, since I have solved the summation of only 2 variables before.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show they are independent, you need to show
$$P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2) = P(Y_1 = y_1) \cdot P(Y_2 = y_2)$$
for any $y_1$ and $y_2$ both integers in $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$.

---

Hint to get you started:

\begin{align}
P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2)
&= P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2, N=y_1+y_2)
\\
&= P(Y_1=y_1, Y_2=y_2 \mid N=y_1+y_2) \cdot P(N=y_1+y_2)
\\
&= P\left(\sum_{k=1}^{y_1+y_2} X_k = y_1\right) \cdot P(N=y_1+y_2).
\end{align}